# How can I use "R.id object = new R.id();" with Build-Tools 3.6.0?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, reflection, android-build-flavors

I have to use different layouts for different build flavors where in one flavor there are ui elements that don't exist in the other flavor.

Earlier I just set elements invisible/gone but now I have a NestedScrollView with a child fragment that contains a RecyclerView.
The child needs a button in one flavor that the other flavor must not have. 
If I just set it invisible or gone the layout doesn't work properly (doesn't scroll and height is much too low).

I copied the layout xml to the path of the flavor and removed the button and used reflection in fragment code to know if the button exists and implement it's code.

```
    Class<R.id> c = R.id.class;
    R.id object = new R.id();
    Field[] fields = c.getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field field : fields)
    {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        try
        {
            if (field.getName().equals("TheButton"))
            {
                Button tBtn = tView.findViewById((Integer) field.get(object));
                if (tBtn != null)
                    tBtn.setOnClickListener(...);
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

After updating to Gradle build tools from 3.5.3 to 3.6.0 I get

> error: id() has private access in id
>           R.id object = new R.id();

for the line

```
R.id object = new R.id();
```

when trying to build.
At the moment I just keep uinge the old build tools but that's no permanent solution, I think.

Can I do something else? I would like to get rid of reflection but if it's really the only way to go it should work with latest build tools...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that build flavors are not worth the effort. They create more problems than they solve. It was not my idea to use them and I will not use them again voluntarily. Even copy & paste between different projects makes less trouble...
I'll remove reflection and will avoid it at all costs in future Android development.